# Estoy usando XMLHttpRequest, para coger un JSON de una API Rest, imprime en consola el JSON pero no logro sacar esa info por HTML en mi web

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy usando XMLHttpRequest, para coger un JSON de una API Rest, imprime en consola el JSON pero no logro sacar esa info por HTML en mi web

Pero por alguna razon no puedo sacar la informacion en la web...

JSON

```html
{
    "success": true,
    "response": {
        "ico": "running",
        "total": "100,000,000 RIDY",
        "total_amount": "2,500,000 EUR",
        "sold": "0 RIDY",
        "sold_amount": "0 EUR",
        "progress": 0,
        "price": 0.025,
        "start": "2022-06-03 19:05:00",
        "end": "2022-07-03 19:05:00",
        "min": 100,
        "max": 100000,
        "soft": 0,
        "soft_amount": "0 EUR",
        "hard": 0,
        "hard_amount": "0 EUR"
    }
}
```

```js
      function JSONRequest(){

          let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          request.open('GET', 'https://ridery.es/public/api/stage?secret=Fpx7WJZhuH9FofuBP3poAfS6');
          request.onload = function() {debugger;
             let todo = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
             document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = todo.total_amount;
          }
          request.send();
      }

      JSONRequest();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

El suelta undefined en el navegador.

Comment: No puedo probar la API por el api_key supongo, pero en todo caso en el fichero JS coloca lo siguiente: `const {total_amount} = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` y luego `const texto = document.createTextNode(total_amount)` y añades bien como lo estás haciendo con el `innerHTML` o puedes probar crear un `<span/>` y colocar `.appendChild()`

Comment: Puedes ver json a travez de esta url https://ridery.es/public/api/stage?secret=Fpx7WJZhuH9FofuBP3poAfS6

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, gracias por tu ayuda.